# Firebase FCM XMPP server error: connection denied due to policy

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement an XMPP server in my Google Cloud module (endpoints) for my Android app using Android Studio in order to send downstream messages to devices.

I have found an example project which uses Smark [here](https://github.com/carlosCharz/fcmxmppserver). The following is the code for the connection:

```
CcsClient ccs = CcsClient.prepareClient(Utils.FCM_ID,Utils.FCM_KEY,false);
try {
    ccs.connect();
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SmackException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I am getting the following SmackException:

```
The following addresses failed: 'fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5236' failed because 
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connection to 
(10, [2607:f8b0:4001:c06::bc]:5236,6) denied due to policy
```

How can I fix this?